# List of list in string format, want to convert to list of list (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

I'm receiving a message that is a list of lists but is recognized as a string in Python. I can't figure out how to get Python to interpret the string as a list of lists, is there a simple way to do this? An example of the format I'm dealing with is shown below:

```
>>soc = '[["hello","world"],["foo","bar"]]'
>>type(soc)
<type 'str'>
```

I want to convert this string into an unaltered list of lists:

```
>>soc
[["hello","world"],["foo","bar"]]
>>type(soc)
<type 'list'>
```

I'd appreciate any help offered, thanks!

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493599/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-list-in-python-to-a-list-object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a string representation of a list in python to a list object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19493599/converting-a-string-representation-of-a-list-in-python-to-a-list-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

```
import ast

soc = '[["hello","world"],["foo","bar"]]'

ast.literal_eval(soc)

# [['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads)

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(soc)
[['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]
```

Answer (score 0):

why not the builtin `eval` function

```
soc = eval('[["hello","world"],["foo","bar"]]')
type(soc)
Out[5]: list

soc
Out[6]: [['hello', 'world'], ['foo', 'bar']]

soc[1][0]
Out[7]: 'foo'
```

and now for the expected objections about 'safety'...